# Basic Bill of Materials schema

Tags: beginner, sql, sql-server

I've been working on Bill of Materials mini schema for a while. At first I had single `Part` table where I've referenced itself. I was told it would be better to have separate table because we'd need to have info like quantity and that quantity is not part of Part itself. Here's the script...

```
CREATE TABLE Part
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    PartNumber NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    ListPrice DECIMAL(12,2) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE BOM
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    PartId INT NOT NULL,
    ParentId INT NULL,
    Quantity INT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE BOM ADD CONSTRAINT BOM_PartId_FK
FOREIGN KEY (PartId) REFERENCES Part(ID)

ALTER TABLE BOM ADD CONSTRAINT BOM_ParentId_FK
FOREIGN KEY (ParentId) REFERENCES Part(ID)

insert into Part (PartNumber, Description, ListPrice) values ('AAA', 'A', 250.00)
insert into Part (PartNumber, Description, ListPrice) values ('AA', 'A', 100.00)
insert into Part (PartNumber, Description, ListPrice) values ('BBB', 'B', 250.00)
insert into Part (PartNumber, Description, ListPrice) values ('BB', 'B', 90.00)
insert into Part (PartNumber, Description, ListPrice) values ('B', 'B', 40.00)

insert into BOM (PartId) values (1)
insert into BOM (PartId, ParentId, Quantity) values (2, 1, 5)
insert into BOM (PartId, ParentId, Quantity) values (4, 3, 10)
insert into BOM (PartId, ParentId, Quantity) values (5, 4, 50)
insert into BOM (PartId, ParentId, Quantity) values (4, 1, 50)
```

Would this be ok as beginner BOM schema?

I've tested with the below query, this gets immediate children of BOM with ID of 1.

```
select e.*
from BOM b
join BOM e on b.PartId = e.ParentId
where b.ID = 1
```

I will recursively call this from c# to populate children from any level in the BOM, but usually top most level.

Comment: Why is the parent of a BOM not another BOM, but a Part?

Comment: What's going to be in the `[Description]` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up casing styles for T-SQL keywords - pick one: `ANNOYINGCASE` or `readablecase`, but don't use both in the same script. I have no bias or preference whatsoever for either*, all that matters is consistency.

Semicolons are not required to indicate the end of a statement, but they are nonetheless a good habit to have.

You inline primary keys and let the server name them. I might have a fetish for naming things, but I like my PK's named `PK_TableName`.

Speaking of naming, the `Part` table should be named `Parts`, and should probably have a *natural key* in the form of a unique constraint on the `PartNumber` column... which I find is a redundant name - `Number` would be better.

Foreign keys have potentially ambiguous names, or will be when your schema grows. I like naming my FK's `FK_ReferencedTable_AlteredTable[_ColumnName]`, where the `[_ColumnName]` part is only needed for when there are multiple FK's on the same table referencing the same table, like when an `OrderHeaders` table references a `FiscalCalendars` table with its `OrderDateCalendarId`, `ShipDateCalendarId` and `CancelDateCalendarId`, which would respectively be `FK_FiscalCalendars_OrderHeaders_OrderDate`, `FK_FiscalCalendars_OrderHeaders_ShipDate` and `FK_FiscalCalendars_OrderHeaders_CancelDate`. So in your case that would be `FK_Parts_BillOfMaterials` and `FK_BillOfMaterials_BillOfMaterials`. Being rigorously consistent about naming foreign keys makes it easy to instantly know what tables are involved and in which direction, just by looking at the FK's name. Oh, and I agree with @RubberDuck - use `BillOfMaterials`, and keep `bom` for table aliases when querying the schema.

You're not specifying the schema you're creating the tables in. Better be explicit; you're not specifying the seed for your `IDENTITY` columns - again, better be explicit.

I hate to see `Description` be syntax-highlighted in SSMS - I like that you're avoiding that by enclosing the name in square brackets. But then, the issue could be avoided altogether by calling the column `Name` instead - that way you don't have to use square brackets *everywhere*, and `Description` doesn't stick out like a sore thumb by being the only name using square brackets.

That said, `NVARCHAR(MAX)` has implications that make it an annoying field, especially if the longest description/name is going to be 200, or even 1024 characters. Don't use `MAX` for anything below 4000 characters.

Also, I think you're abusing `NULL` columns. Does a part that has no number, no description and no price really make sense? Wouldn't that rather be an *empty* number, an *empty* description and a 0 price?

Comma-first style makes it easier to change the order of the columns if you ever want to do that.

Lastly, and again this might be just me, but I like when I can run a T-SQL script twice in a row without it blowing up or doing weird things.

Putting it all together (making a few assumptions):

```
use [database_name]; -- trust me, this one is a life saver
go;

/* drop FK constraints */

if exists (select * from sys.foreign_keys where name = 'FK_BillOfMaterials_BillOfMaterials')
    alter table BillOfMaterials drop constraint FK_BillOfMaterials_BillOfMaterials;

if exists (select * from sys.foreign_keys where name = 'FK_Parts_BillOfMaterials')
    alter table BillOfMaterials drop constraint FK_Parts_BillOfMaterials;


/* drop tables */

if exists (select * from sys.tables where name = 'Parts')
    drop table Parts;

if exists (select * from sys.tables where name = 'BillOfMaterials')
    drop table BillOfMaterials;


/* create tables */

create table dbo.Parts (
     Id int identity(1,1) not null
    ,Number nvarchar(50) not null
    ,Name nvarchar(250) not null
    ,ListPrice decimal(12,2) not null -- 2 decimals might be a little short in some cases
    ,constraint PK_Parts primary key clustered (Id)
    ,constraint NK_Parts unique (Number) -- "NK" == "Natural Key" (assumption here)
);

create table dbo.BillOfMaterials (
     Id int identity(1,1) not null
    ,PartId int not null
    ,ParentId int null
    ,Quantity int not null
    ,constraint PK_BillOfMaterials primary key clustered (Id)
);


/* add FK constraints */

alter table dbo.BillOfMaterials add constraint FK_BillOfMaterials_BillOfMaterials 
    foreign key (ParentId) references dbo.BillOfMaterials (Id);

alter table dbo.BillOfMaterials add constraint FK_Parts_BillOfMaterials 
    foreign key (PartId) references dbo.Parts (Id);
```

---

<sub>*cough</sub>

Answer (score 2):

It's ok, but there's room for improvement.

1. Don't use `BOM`. Use `BillOfMaterials`. 
   It won't matter to you, but the next guy will thank me.
2. You're missing indexes on the items you defined foreign keys for. They're not free, you have to create them yourself.
3. I find it really odd that the `BOM.Quantity` can be null. If a part is on the BoM, shouldn't there be *at least one* of them required as part of the "kit"? I may even consider using a default value of one.